# gmail blocking rails app from sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, gmail

I'm pretty sure I have everythign configured right, but I keep getting          'Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at' error when trying to send mails through my rails app.  Also, there is only a blank space after the 'at' in the error message so I don't even know where to look for more information.   I am also 100% sure the password and email are correct.

in my config/development.rb  (I also have this in application.rb)

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
 # SMTP settings for gmail

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { 

 :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
 :port                 => 587,
 :domain               => 'gmail.com',
 :user_name            => 'username@gmail.com',
 :password             => 'password',
 :authentication       => 'plain',
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

I have allowed less secure apps access on the actual gmail account.

Comment: Are you using 2F authentication?

Comment: Yes, I'm having the same issue also i tried port 465

Answer (score 15):

Google blocks all suspicious login attempts. By using app password, I was able to solve the problem:

1. Enable 2-Step Verification if you haven't done so.
2. Go to [App passwords](https://myaccount.google.com/u/2/apppasswords) (Google will ask you to login again to verify here)
3. Create a new App password: Choose **Other (Custom name)** under *Select app*, then enter app's name (any name you want)
4. Click generate, a popup will be shown with a password. Use that password in your rails configuration instead of your google password.

Comment: This isn't working. At least not for my configuration. Any suggestions? I have essentially the same smtp settings as the original post does, except i'm using a business gmail account with GSuite and I'm using my own domain in the option that says domain. I.e., `domain: 'mydomain.com'`

Comment: @AngelGarcia I'm not 100% sure, but from your comment, the problem may be the business account. Can you try using a normal account in dev environment?

Comment: Yes! A normal account does indeed work. Just not the business account.

Comment: hi @AngelGarcia do you remember what was the root cause with your business domain?

Comment: `domain: yourcompany.com` is the right way, but also it's worth to check https://admin.google.com - security - basic settings - less secure apps setting. In my case this issue is sorted using company's email address.

Answer (score 5):

This is the config that works for me with Google apps for business.  Try changing your port to 465

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  tls: true,
  address:              ENV["EMAIL_URL"],
  port:                 465,
  domain:               ENV["EMAIL_DOMAIN"],
  user_name:            ENV["EMAIL_USER_NAME"],
  password:             ENV["EMAIL_PASSWORD"],
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

Comment: Worked for me.  Thanks.